# Sample code java Browserstack and Saucelabs

Tags: api, rest, testing, saucelabs, browserstack

I am newbie here on stackoverflow.

I am beginner with the tools test as a service and I need a very simple sample code on how to use the REST API Saucelabs and BrowserStack to facilitate my studies, could be the same example, but implemented with the two tools.

Could someone help me?

Best Regards,
Ricardo.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HttpClient` in Java to make the REST API calls. For more details, you can refer the sample given under BrowserStack's documentation here:

https://www.browserstack.com/automate/java#rest-api

Answer (score 0):

I have written a browserstack java API that you can use.

http://browserstack4j.sourceforge.net/